# Python multi-threading with tkinter

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm trying to build a Tkinter GUI that is sort of like a personal assistant, however I've fallen at the fist hurdle :( When I update the GUI and listen with speech_recognition, it freezes and says not responding! I understand that I need to use multi threading however I'm stuck on how to use it!

Here's my code and my failed attempt at using multi-threading.

```
import tkinter as tk
from subprocess import call as say
import winsound
import speech_recognition as sr
import threading

def cbc(tex):

    return lambda : callback(tex)

def callback(tex):
    button = "Listen" 

    tex.insert(tk.END, button)
    tex.see(tk.END)# Scroll if necessary



def listen(tex):
    def callback(tex):
        g = ("Say,,your,,command,,after,,the,,beep")
        say('espeak '+ g, shell = True)

        winsound.Beep(1000,500)


        ltext = 'listening...'
        tex.insert(tk.END, ltext)

        r = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            damand = r.listen(source)

        damandtxt = (recognizer_google(damand))
        tex.insert(tk5.END, damandtxt)

        tex.see(tk.END)


    t3 = threading.Thread(target = callback(tex))
    t3.daemon = True
    t3.start()

top = tk.Tk()
tex = tk.Text(master=top)
tex.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
bop = tk.Frame()
bop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)


tk.Button(bop, text='Listen', command=lambda: listen(tex)).pack()
tk.Button(bop, text='Exit', command=top.destroy).pack()

top.mainloop()
```

I just need to know how to use it correctly. Please

p.s I've read all the documentation and everything on multi-threading but it just doesn't work :'(

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You're calling your thread incorrectly,

```
 t3 = threading.Thread(target = callback(tex))
```

`callback(tex)` is calling the function, instead of passing it in as the target. If you want to use it this way you need to use `target = lambda: callback(tex)`

You should be using the thread like this:

```
 t3 = threading.Thread(target = callback, args=(tex,))
```

Also on another note, you really don't need that function nested inside of your other function, you can move it outside and it will have the `tex` arguement since you are passing the arguement to your thread.